# Get selected view name from list view web part in client side rendering JSLink

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, list-view, client-side-rendering

I have created one page and added a list view web part on it.

I have added JSLink in Web part properties for client side rendering. All is working well but I want to get the currently selected View name to get specific view data.

How can this be done?

Comment: You are not getting list items, right ?.. is that mean there is something wrong with the rendering of your view? Can you please provide more information...

Comment: I presume you do work with Cisar, https://github.com/andrei-markeev/cisar

Comment: my view have enabled grouping so rendering data gives only gouping field details like Grouping field value, item count etc. i want all items of view.

Answer (score 1):

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {  
  SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
    OnPostRender: function(ctx) {  
       var viewtitle = ctx.viewTitle;
        console.log("Your View Name" + viewtitle );     
    }
  }); 
});
```

Comment: it's working if i add JSLink on list's default page, but it's not working on other pages.

Comment: add this in to script file and add link to JS link in that webpart, write back to  a global variable

Comment: i have already tried it.

Comment: Please check the below answer

Answer (score 0):

It works.check below console. Added inthe script referred to JS link. Please find below image for the above answer

[image: Add JS to App part in custom page]

Comment: the view guid is current list view web part's current view's guid, there isn't available any view with this guid in list settings. just go to list setting and compare all view's guid with this one.

Comment: This view is dynamicaaly genearated and will not be avaible in the list settings. if you want  list data it is accessible via ctx.ListData

Comment: But when we use grouping in view the ctx.ListData return only grouping field details like group field value, item count etc. it's not returning all fields value.

Comment: State all your requirements so that some one can correcty address the question